# .gitignore for xcworkspace, not just xcodeproj?

Tags: xcode, gitignore

I have a .gitignore file in MyProject.xcodeproj which ignores the xcuserdata, but the directory is not ignored in my MyProject.xcworkspace and I can't figure out how to do it there? Any suggestions?

Comment: What's in your `.gitignore` file?

Comment: Just xcuserdata for now. When I try to change branch it tells me that I've uncommited changes.

Comment: What are the changes that are uncommitted? Changes to your .gitignore?

Comment: It is the UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate file that keeps changing, so I don't want to commit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the content of that folder is not *already* tracked:

```
git rm --cached [project].xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/*
git commit -m "Removed previously track xcuserdata content"
```

Then your `.gitignore` would apply automatically.